# Renting in Germany: how do I get a SCHUFA?

Tags: germany, rental, accommodation

While looking for flats to rent I saw that someone aks for a SCHUFA.
What do I need to do in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s been a while (five years, to be exact) since I last applied for a flat. However, in my limited experience it is not *you* who provides the Schufa exerpt. Rather, you sign a slip giving the landlord permission to perform a Schufa lookup. The landlord then requests the details, submitting why he needs them, Schufa checks if they have a file on you and if so forwards only the information the landlord needs to know in a rather basic form.

You can also check your own Schufa record. This requires filling out a form from the respective site, printing it, adding a return envelope with your address and sufficient stamps (iirc) and then sending it by mail. They will send you a much more detailed breakdown of their data on you, including who requested a lookup when. Under no circumstances should this extensive data be forwarded to the landlord.

Answer (score 5):

As a prospective tenant, the landlord is expecting you to obtain a [credit report](https://www.meineschufa.de/downloads/SCHUFA_Infoblatt-BA-Antrag-englisch.pdf), through the German credit bureau, [SCHUFA](https://www.meineschufa.de/index.php).

Comment: One question: in the second page of the document you linked, they ask for a "copy of official residency certificate", but how do I get it if I am still looking for a flat?

Comment: Are you in Germany on a visa, and will there for more than three months? If so, foreigners (from outside the EU) apply for a residence permit (Aufenthaltstitel) at the local Foreigners Office (Ausländerbehörde).

Comment: I will move to Germany in a week, but I am still looking for a flat..the fact is that many of the Ads I find on the internet asks for this SCHUFA. I tried contacting the owners even if I do not have a SCHUFA, but they never answer and I though the problem might have been the missing SCHUFA

Comment: Then check at the German Embassy or consulate in your country to see if you're able to directly apply for a residence permit before you depart for Germany (possible in some locations, not all).

Comment: Do I need a residence permit even if I come from an EU country?

Comment: Yes, easier as an EU citizen, you just need a registration certificate (Meldeschein) which you get at the Registry Office (Einwohnermeldeamt) in the city neighborhood you intend to settle. Everyone does this, Germans included.